# How does c++ sizeof works?

Tags: c++, memory, sizeof

I have following code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
    int a;
    char* b;
};

class B {
    int a;
};

class C {
    char *b;
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    cout << "size of A:" << sizeof(A) << endl;
    cout << "size of B:" << sizeof(B) << endl;
    cout << "size of C:" << sizeof(C) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

link to ideone : https://ideone.com/OAQuMv

Size of A is 16

Size of B is 4

Size of C is 8

Why size of A is 16 not 12?

Comment: Sizes of fundamental types depend on the platform. Sizes of structs depend on the compiler and options, since the compiler can add padding for efficiency.

Comment: I suspect it is because of alignment, the char * starting upon a multiple of 8 bytes. Ty swap int a and char *b in class A. Is the result the same?

Comment: yes the result is the same.